# How to print public static final members in mongodb in a Java application?

Tags: java, mongodb, playframework, morphia

I'm using Play-Morphia to create my application, and I have a class which has a public static final members, and when I use the find() function on my object, I get the object but only with its public or private members, but not its public static final members.
for example:

```
public class Person{
    public String name;
    public int age;
    public static final String id;
}
```

Now, after saving this object to Mongo and then calling Person.find().first() or any Person.find() functions, I get: {"name" : "John", "age" : 30} --> with no ID included.

Does anyone has a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

static variables are at class level, while mongodb entities are corresponding to each object. Therefore static variables will not be saved into mongodb collection. Can you let us know why you want to put a static (and even final) variable into mongodb? What's your business logic?

Comment: I want to be able to save the Person's data, retrieve it for a client request and let him/her to make changes in that Person but not to change the Person's ID, while the client should be able to see the Person's ID if he/she wants to copy it or something, and finally save it again,

Comment: Is that person's ID common to all person? If the answer is negative then you should NOT use `static` scope.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you'd be better off making the id field of type ObjectId. So I'd recommend a setup like this:

```
public class Person{

  private final ObjectId id = new ObjectId();
  private String name;
  private int age;

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

The ObjectId can be generated on the client side and is guaranteed to be unique. Note that you should **not** have the static flag, but the **final** indicate that the field should not be changeable.

Make the fields themselves private and just don't provide a setter for id - that way other parts of your code won't be able to affect the id field.

Comment: The ID field is just an example here. In my real application I have many different kinds of objects that are static final which I'd like to print...

Comment: I think you really need to read about and understand how static works in Java, see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html